# Minecraft, without the death?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition

I think Minecraft is fun for its progression.

First you start with a plain world that you sculpt, mine and craft to your choosing or (with mods for example) you start with a system that's small, tedious, or inefficient that you upgrade to be large scale and fast. It's this "building up" that I like about Minecraft.

However, what's been getting in the way for me from having this fun is simply: Death. Death in Minecraft is unforgiving. To me, preventing death feels like a requirement and isn't something I really enjoy doing. I don't really like having to dodge lava or stay inside at night or ensure total torch lighting in my house.

**How can I play in survival mode but make it such that things don't hurt?** I'm hoping somebody could suggest a way/mod for me that simply *takes away damage* without *getting in the way*.

Minecraft is a sandbox game, and I should be able to define the experience--this is a theme that underpins the entire Minecraft community, from pvp minigame servers to complex mods. I'm hoping we can avoid discussion on how the game "should be" played.

Some ideas that were suggested to me are the following, as well as explanations on why they aren't really what I'm looking for:

- Creative mode adds flying, items on demand from the GUI, and other things I perceive as game-breaking. Most of the content is designed under the assumption that you're playing on surival mode.
- Invincible (or near it) suits of armor would feel a bit too cheated in, violate my idea of step-by-step progress, and prevent me from wearing armor I craft myself.
- Removing all the mobs would take away drops I may need for crafting (e.g. Ender Pearls).

Thanks!

Comment: Previous comments on this question have been [moved to chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/17748/discussion-on-question-by-t-mart-minecraft-without-the-death)

Comment: @Ataxia Do you want a mod that completely disables death, even from things that you normally wouldn't be able to do in vanilla survival mode, like falling into the void or getting /kill by an admin? Or just disable death from falling, mob damage, lava and so on?

Comment: @Chippies I just want a mod that prevents the player from dying.  Void should not be problem; neither should admin.  Just disabling natural death.

Comment: Well,I've beaten the Ender Dragon without dying ever on that world. So Minecraft "without" deaths is somehow possible if you are focused enough,armoured with a diamond enchanted armour with at least Protection 4 and Feather Falling 4,with potions and with golden apples.

Comment: Why don't you just add an infinite armor? You claim it feels "cheaty", but what's the point of armor if there is no damage?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

It is not yet updated to the latest version of Minecraft (currently still on 1.6.2) but [Single Player Commands](http://www.minecraftforum.net/forums/mapping-and-modding/minecraft-mods/1272348-single-player-commands-v4-9-official-download-spc) basically takes a lot of cheaty commands and adds them in single-player mode.

If you install this, use the command `/health infinite`

You now get 'hit' as normal, can be killed by insta-death effects like falling into the Void, but otherwise have infinite HP.

For 1.7.9 there is [MrChris' GodMode](http://www.curse.com/bukkit-plugins/minecraft/mrchris-godmode) mode which does much the same thing.

Answer (score 32):

Here's a suggestion:

If you're playing Vanilla, you can always create a set of command blocks that constantly heals and gives resistance to the player.

---

Firstly, you'll have to start the world in Creative Mode and cheats (you can switch back to Survival once you've complete this setup and play from there; that's one of the reasons you need cheats enabled).

Then, give yourself a command block.
`/give @p minecraft:command_block 1`

Now, create a loop of command blocks; a clock chain, preferably looping every 3 seconds.

Create command blocks, with the following commands:
`/effect @a 10 2401 1 true` (Regeneration)
`/effect @a 11 2401 100 true` (Resistance)
`/effect @a 12 2401 1 true` (Fire Resistance)
`/effect @a 6 2401 20 true` (Instant Health)
`/effect @a 23 2401 20 true` (Hunger Saturation - If you do not want hunger to deplete)
`/gamerule keepInventory true` (Keeps the inventory and XP on death)

Now, make sure your command blocks do not get destroyed (ie. Protect it by covering the whole contraption with bedrock) and now, you can turn back into Survival mode with
`/gamemode @p 0` and play on from there.

EDIT: Resistance does protect you from fall damage. It prevents pretty much any form of damage, as long as the protection is high enough.
So, falling from 255 height to 1 can be protected with: `/effect @a 11 5 251` (Resistance to 254-3; 125.5 hearts of damage)

---

As for mods that does this; there's none that I've heard of.

If you would like screenshots or a video tutorial, I don't mind making one.

---

As of MC 1.8 Potion effects via the effects command is no longer using the ID system. Here are the commands for MC 1.8

```
/effect @a minecraft:regeneration 1000000 255 true
/effect @a minecraft:resistance 1000000 255 true
/effect @a minecraft:fire_resistance 1000000 255 true
/effect @a minecraft:instant_health 1000000 255 true
/effect @a minecraft:saturation 1000000 255 true
```

---

As of MC 1.13, they changed the syntax:

```
/effect give @a minecraft:regeneration 1000000 255 true
/effect give @a minecraft:resistance 1000000 255 true
/effect give @a minecraft:fire_resistance 1000000 255 true
/effect give @a minecraft:instant_health 1000000 255 true
/effect give @a minecraft:saturation 1000000 255 true
```

Comment: Your command blocks will have to be kept loaded too. And falling from high enough to die from the damage in one hit would still kill you.

Comment: Resistance protects you for fall damage. If you're worried about falling from the top of the world to the bottom....... Then just give yourself Level 251 (or higher) resistance instead of 100. (`/effect @a 11 5 251`)

Comment: Still, the block has to be kept loaded, right?

Comment: Yes. That's the only downside @Lohoris. If you're worried the chunk gets unloaded - Just make the effects permanent; change the duration variable to a high number (equating to more than 20 minutes, in seconds), like 2401; 20 minutes and 1 second.

Comment: there are mods that add armor that is pretty OP

Comment: You should list your answer @ratchetfreak.

Comment: Can't you keep the command block loaded by putting it in your [spawn chunks](http://minecraft.gamepedia.com/Spawn_chunk)?

Comment: @BrendanLong That's correct. If you need to go to the Nether, you'll need to set up a rig in the spawn chunks to spit an item into a nether portal every 45 seconds or so to keep the Overworld's spawn chunks loaded.

Comment: @mouseas Or you can put an identical setup of command blocks in the Nether.

Comment: You could just put the effects' duration to infinite.

Comment: You can put the command block array in the spawn chunk, and set the duration to an arbitrarily long time. Also, you only need resistance 5 to completely negate all damage (with the exception of void damage, *which for technical reasons cannot be disabled by a mod or otherwise*).

Comment: As of 1.13, you need to write `/effect give` instead of just `/effect`

Comment: Is it really necessary to include the syntax for now-five-year-old versions of Minecraft in the answer.

Answer (score 12):

There is a mod called [Extra Utilities](http://www.minecraftforum.net/forums/mapping-and-modding/minecraft-mods/wip-mods/1443963-extra-utilities-v1-1-0k) that, among other things, adds a [Peaceful Table](http://ftbwiki.org/Peaceful_Table). This table allows players who play the game on **Peaceful** difficulty to get mob drops.

Taken from the wiki directly:

> The Peaceful Table is a block added by Extra Utilities, that allows players who play on peaceful to get mob drops. In order for the table to work, it has to be placed in the world adjacent to a chest (or any block with an inventory) which has a sword in it. The table will occasionally spawn a mob and kill it instantly with the provided sword. The sword will take damage appropriate to the hits needed to kill the mob with the sword in the inventory. In other words, better swords last longer. Enchantments are also taken into account. Looting will give extra mob drops. Sharpness and Unbreaking will make the swords last longer.
>
> A Peaceful Table may be placed in the Nether in order to get Nether mob drops; but must be placed in a Nether Fortress in order to get Blaze and Wither Skeleton drops. A Peaceful Table may be placed in the End in order to get Enderman drops.

If you use this mod, craft this table, and have your difficulty set to Peaceful, I see all of your objectives as met.

Comment: I should point out, that the last line is somewhat misleading. Having not used the table myself, I would *assume* that placing the table in The End will *only* net endermen drops, rather than that being the only way to get endermen drops. Because of course, otherwise, reaching the end to get said drops would be impossible.

Comment: Not impossible:  you can buy eyes of ender from villagers instead of crafting them from ender pearls.

Answer (score 7):

There is a mod called Gravestone, it adds in a gravestone that will spawn were you die, containing all of your items, indefinitely, or until you come and break it, getting your items back.

Comment: Even after dying in lava pool?

Comment: Even dying in a lava pool. You have to clear out the lava though @user11153

Answer (score 6):

This isn't exactly what you asked for, but I suggest that an option worth considering because it is simple and already available in the game is:

```
/gamerule keepInventory true
```

Like all `gamerule`s, the effect of this command lasts forever (so no gimmicks with command blocks are needed).  You do need to enable cheats to be able to set it (either at world creation time or by temporarily using "Open to LAN").

What it does is, in the event that you die, when you respawn *you will still have all of your inventory items and levels*. Thus death merely means you teleport back to your last bed or spawn point — since you don't lose any items, you haven't really lost any of your *progress in the game*. Death is no more inconvenient than falling down a ravine and having to climb your way back up, or getting completely lost in a cave.

Comment: This is a great idea. Sometimes, what people want isn't what they say they want (see [this discussion](http://uxmyths.com/post/746610684/myth-21-people-can-tell-you-what-they-want)). I've actually been using this solution, despite accepting another answer that addresses my request more explicitly. Further, you also exposed me to `/gamerule` ([docs](http://minecraft.gamepedia.com/Commands#gamerule)) which offers a `/gamerule mobGriefing false`, disallowing mobs to modify blocks; this too is something I was looking for, but didn't realize at the time.

Comment: If you don't want "Allow Cheats: ON" forever, create your world with that set to "OFF", and then press `ESC` and press "open to lan". Then make sure "Allow Cheats" is set to "ON" and press OK. Then open the chat and type `/gamerule keepInventory true`. Then exit your world and open it again. The gamerule should still be there, but you can't change it without doing the steps above.

Comment: @nelson2tm Thanks for the reminder. I've never used that trick so I didn't think of it.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to stop the negatives of death try an inventory keeping mod, and a teleporter mod, if you die,you can just respawn at your bed/spawn and hop over to where you were, no progress lost, almost as if you never died.

Becoming invincible is a bad idea for anyone asking, not only does it make mobs laughable (which really does take the "surviving" aspect out of survival mode) , it can also break the game, i mean what happens if you fall into the void?, you'll be stuck.

If you hate lava, Pack some enchanted golden apples using cheats, they'll give you fire resistance long enough. (if you don't like the damage resistance or the regen, you can always pack a stack of spider eyes to reverse the effect).

Answer (score -4):

If you are interested in using mods, there are a number of mods that either give extremely overpowered armor or can give this power to the player directly.

The Yogscast Complete Pack has a number of these, and you can use the Yogscast Let's Plays on Youtube to figure out how they work:

- The Mad Scientist Mod (genetically modifies the player using genomes extracted from mobs);
- Tinker's Construct (allows you to make armor that is far stronger than the default, from new materials);
- there are also several mods that include modular power armor;
- Thaumcraft, Witchery, Ars Magica (and maybe others) also have effects that allow you to survive things that you normally wouldn't survive, like swimming in lava, falling from great heights, or even heavy explosions.

I have not used the YCP personally, but since nearly every member of the Yogscast uses it, there are many references on Youtube on how it works, although you might need to take notes.

Please note that this modpack does also add a number of stronger mobs, including stronger creepers, deadlier Nether, various elementals,...

Comment: But those mods are not meant to be used like that. Also, to point something out with Thaumcraft - You can't simply "give" yourself auras/buffs (unless you don't mind constantly giving yourself Vis every... minute or two), and Thaumcraft isn't as simple as 1-2-3-cast [and then insert the effect the stays forever until your run out of Vis; mana]!

Comment: I think @t-mart wants to play vanilla minecraft with only the mods that do what they asked. These mods also add other items to minecraft, which he probably doesn't want.